# How to end a while loop

Tags: java

My program for class asks to run the program as long as the user doesn't enter the input of -99. When I run the program and enter a usable number that isn't -99, the console will run a continuous looping answer until I have to press end. 
How can I change the program so for each input there will be one answer and the program restarts until user inputs -99?

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner 
import java.io.*; //import library 

public class is_odd_or_even_number {//begin class

   public static void main(String []args) {//begin main

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      //use try/catch method to test for invalid input
      try{
      //promt user to input a value 
      System.out.print("Enter a positive integer value: ");
      int number = input.nextInt();

      //PART I NEED HELP WITH **************
      while (number != -99){
      //Start of if statement to test which to print and call of isEven method
         if (isEven(number)) {
         System.out.println("Your number is Even!");  
         }
         else 
         System.out.println("Your number is Odd!");

         }
      }
      //open catch method and print invalid 
      catch(Exception notNumber) {
         System.out.println("Input not a number, try again.");
      }
   }
   //begin testing for odd or even in new method 
   public static boolean isEven(int num){
         return(num & 1) == 0;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you don't let the user entry other thing that the first input before the loop.

The retrieval of the input from the user :

```
  int number = input.nextInt();
```

should be in the loop.

Try that :

```
  int number = 0;

  //PART I NEED HELP WITH **************
  while (number != -99){
    number = input.nextInt();

    //Start of if statement to test which to print and call of isEven method
     if (isEven(number)) {
       System.out.println("Your number is Even!");  
     }
     else 
       System.out.println("Your number is Odd!");
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this way ;)

```
System.out.print("Enter a positive integer value: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        //PART I NEED HELP WITH **************
        while (number != -99){
            System.out.print("Not good, please enter a new one : ");
            number = input.nextInt();
        }
        //Start of if statement to test which to print and call of isEven method
        if (isEven(number)) {
            System.out.println("Your number is Even!");  
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your number is Odd!");

        }
```

So it will ask until you're not writing -99 as you said, but if you're asking for "a positive int" normally nobofy would write -99 :p

Answer (score 0):

### End a while loop

You can use a boolean value `shouldContinue` to control whether the programs should continue to the next input.

```
if (number != -99) {
    shouldContinue = true;
} else {
    shouldContinue = false;
}
```

This can be simplified as follow:

```
shouldContinue = number != -99 ? true : false;
// or even shorter
shouldContinue = number != -99;
```

### Read the value correctly

But you need to ensure that you input number is reset at each loop execution so that you can read the next number:

```
while (shouldContinue) {
    ...
    number = input.nextInt();
}
```

### Other enhancements

- Do not import unused packages or classes
- Use camel case for Java class name
- Use comment style `/** ... */` for Javadoc
- Always try to avoid infinite loop, e.g. use an integer count `tries` and count down at each loop.

Here's the final answer look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IsOddOrEvenNumber {

    public static void main(String []args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean shouldContinue = true;
        int tries = 0;

        while (shouldContinue && tries < 10) {

            try {
                System.out.print("Enter a positive integer value: ");
                int number = input.nextInt();
                if (isEven(number)) {
                    System.out.println("Your number is Even!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your number is Odd!");
                }
                shouldContinue = number != -99 ? true : false;
            } catch (Exception notNumber) {
                System.out.println("Input not a number, try again.");
            }
            tries--;
        }
        System.out.println("Game over.");
    }

    /**
     * Begin testing for odd or even in new method
     */
    public static boolean isEven(int num){
        return (num & 1) == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you are the `main` method which will be running as long as user is not entering -99;

You should include all your code in the `while` loop (even try/catch).

```
public static void main(String []args) {//begin main

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int number = 0;
  //Keep application running as long as the input is not -99
  while (number != -99){

     //use try/catch method to test for invalid input
     try{
        //promt user to input a value 
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer value: ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        //Start of if statement to test which to print and call of isEven method
        //if the entered number is -99, the following code will skipped.
        if(number == -99) continue;

        if (isEven(number))
           System.out.println("Your number is Even!");  
        else 
           System.out.println("Your number is Odd!");
     }
     //open catch method and print invalid 
     catch(Exception notNumber) {
         System.out.println("Input not a number, try again.");
     }
  }
}
```

You could accept this answer, in case it is what you are looking for :)